# Redis Memory Restart

Tags: redis

This is a quick questions I couldn't find with general Google search or Stackoverflow search. If you have a Master-Slave Redis cluster, and the RAM is increasing too large for the system - and you reboot the box - what happens to the data? The data is being saved to the disk, but will it be ready to be pulled when the box comes back up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have AOF or RDB enabled, after a reboot the data will be back again in Redis. However just before shutting down Redis don't forget to start a SAVE command.